# How to move product.info.mailto block in custom layout file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, email, social

In vendor file

> \magento226\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

I found

```
<container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                        <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"
                                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" />
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                        </container>
                    </container>
```

Now I want to move product.info.mailto block in custom layout file and for that, I added this is in

> /app/design/frontend/Local/argento-stripes-custom/Swissup_Amp/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.mailto" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
```

parent theme is luma but its not working